# Pass filter parameter to URL in JQGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, jqgrid

I have a JQgrid that is built using the below code (shortened for brevity)

```
function LoadGrid() {
        var myGrid = $('#jqpurchases'),
            selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),

            //docid = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'docid');
            docid = '10001';

        jQuery("#jqpurchases").jqGrid({
            url: '../WebService1.asmx/getDataPurchases',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            ajaxSelectOptions: {
                type: "POST", // one need allows GET in the webmethod (UseHttpGet = true)
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    id: function () {
                        return JSON.stringify($("#jqpurchases").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'));
                    }
                }
            },
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
                if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
                if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
                if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            //postData: { docid: docid },
            jsonReader: {
                root: function (obj) {
                    return typeof obj.d.rows === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d.rows) : obj.d.rows;
                },
                page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
                total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; },
                repeatitems: false
            },
            loadComplete: function () {

                $('#jqpurchaseitems').trigger('reloadGrid');

            },
            loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                    'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                    'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 15],
            colNames: ['Doc ID', 'Purchase #', 'Date', 'Supplier'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    key: true, name: 'docid', index: 'docid', editable: true, formatter: 'showlink', searchtype: "integer", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'lt', 'gt'] }, formatoptions:
                    {           
                        baseLinkUrl: 'Purchases.aspx',  target: '_new'
                    }
                },   
                { name: 'purchase_number', index: 'purchase_number', width: 35, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'lt', 'gt'] }, },
                {
                    name: 'purchase_date', formatter: 'date', datefmt: "d-m-Y", editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s", newformat: "d-m-Y" }, index: 'quote_date', width: 50, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'lt', 'gt'] },
                },
                {
                    name: 'sup_name', index: 'sup_name', width: 85, align: "left", editable: true, edittype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: '/WebService1.asmx/getSuppliersDD',
                        buildSelect: function (data) {
                            var response = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                            var s = '<select id="sup_name" name="sup_name">';
                            if (response && response.length) {
                                s += '<option value="' + "" + '">' + "(Please choose one)" + '</option>';
                                for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
                                    s += '<option value="' + response[i]["supid"] + '">' + response[i]["sup_name"] + '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            return s + "</select>";
                        },

                    }
                }

            ],
            multipleSearch: false,
            multipleGroup: false,
            stringResult: true,
            searchOnEnter: false,
            showQuery: true,
            pager: "#jqpurchasesPager",
            sortname: 'docid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Purchase Orders",
            gridview: true,
            gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = $("#jqpurchases").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
                if (ids.length > 0) {
                    $("#jqpurchases").jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
                    showDetailsGrid();
                }

                var myUrl = jQuery("#jqpurchases").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'url');
                //myUrl += "?myextraparam=something";
                var postData = jQuery("#jqpurchases").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
                $.each(postData, function (key, value) {
                    myUrl += "&" + key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
                });
                alert(myUrl);


            },
            onSelectRow: showDetailsGrid,
            loadonce: false,  //Important - Doesn't work without (server side paging and sorting required)

        }).navGrid('#jqpurchasesPager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true }, // options
            {
                url: '../WebService1.asmx/modifyDataPurchase',
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    var myGrid = $('#jqpurchases'),
                        selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

                    purchase_number = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'purchase_number');

                    if (purchase_number) {
                        alert("This PO has already been generated!");
                        $("#editmod" + "jqpurchases").find(".ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").click();
                    }

                    $('#docid', form).attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#purchase_number', form).attr("disabled", true);

                },
                afterShowForm: function () { },
                ajaxEditOptions: {
                    type: "POST", // one need allows GET in the webmethod (UseHttpGet = true)
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                },
                recreateForm: true,
                serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                    if (postData.exercise_value === undefined) { postData.exercise_value = null; }
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                }
            }, // edit options
            {
                url: "../WebService1.asmx/addDataPurchases",
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    $('#docid', form).attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#purchase_number', form).attr("disabled", true);
                },
                onInitializeForm: function () { },
                ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                recreateForm: true,
                serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                    if (postData.exercise_value === undefined) { postData.exercise_value = null; }
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                }
            },  // add options
            {
                url: "../WebService1.asmx/deleteDataPurchases",
                ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {

                    var myGrid = $('#jqpurchases'),
                        selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

                    purchase_number = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'purchase_number');

                    if (purchase_number) {
                        alert("You cannot delete a generated PO!");
                        $("#delmod" + "jqpurchases").find(".ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").click();
                    }
                },
                serializeDelData: function (postData) {
                    if (postData.exercise_value === undefined) { postData.exercise_value = null; }
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                }
            },   //del options
            {
                multipleSearch: true,
                recreateFilter: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                overlay: false
            },  // search options

        ).navButtonAdd('#jqpurchasesPager', {
                buttonicon: "",
                title: "Generate PO",
                caption: "Generate<br>PO",
                position: "last",
                onClickButton: Generate
            }).navButtonAdd('#jqpurchasesPager', {
                    caption: "Export",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
                onClickButton: Export,
                position: "last"
             });
    }//End of jqpurchases grid
```

I am trying to make it so that when I click the DocID link in the first column, it opens a new webpage, Purchases.ASPX and filters it based on the row where the URL was clicked.

I have implemented this code, which builds the URL, which looks like:

https://localhost:44338/Ordering/Purchases.aspx?id=10005

But when the page loads, it displays **all** the results in the table.

How can I get it to load the page and just show in the table id 10005?

NB. I have already implemented server side searching, if that's required.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only that you should check in this case is your server side code. If you load all the data this means that your either does not accept the parameter correct or your server code is not correct.

Comment: Thanks Tony, makes sense. I have resolved the issue by getting the parameter from my URL and passing to the code behind, using a SQL WHERE clause to filter the results